# Azure DevOps API creating work item returns 404 error

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am attempting to add a work task using Azure Apis but I keep getting a 404 error. I attempted to do a get all projects and this works (so my authentication token is working fine). I even granted all Azure Permissions to the token and it still returns a 404 error.

```cs
public class Main
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      AzureClient ac = new AzureClient();
      var task = ac.AddTask();
   }
}

public class AzureClient 
{
   private readonly HttpClient _client;

   public AzureClient()
   {
      _client = new HttpClient()
      {
         Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
      };

      _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
      // ADDED PAT HERE TO CLIENT
   }

   public async Task AddTask()
   {
      List<object> task = new List<object>
      {
         new { op = "add", path = "/fields/System.Title", value = "Test"}
      };

      string jsonTask = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(task);
      string baseUri = "some base uri";
      string uri = $"{baseUri}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=5.0";
      
      // RESPONSE HERE RETURNS 404
      var response = _client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(jsonTask, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json")).Result;
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the `baseUri` variable set to? Look at the `uri` variable and ensure it's correct. Also, you should `await` the call to `PostAsync` to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: @DanielMann I am going to fix the async part thanks. The base uri I can confirm works since I tested the following url and it returns a list of projects under my organization "baseUri/_apis/projects?api-version=5.0"

Comment: The REST API URI needs to contain the project name or ID. As I said, look at the `uri` variable. Don't assume it's correct. Compare that URI to the REST API documentation.

Comment: @DanielMann yes it contains the projectname within the base and the full uri matches exactly what microsoft is asking for

Comment: I thought that the payload may have needed the from attribute so I added that with an empty string as it's value but that didn't work.

Comment: Are you targeting Azure DevOps Server/TFS on-prem or are you targeting Azure DevOps? If you're targeting Azure DevOps, I'd strongly recommend using the latest REST API version, which is 6.1. Beyond that, unless you're willing to provide the exact URI you're trying to access, there's not much more guidance anyone can give you. The 404 error means you're not giving it a valid URI to the API.

Comment: Not on cloud so we are using 5.0 for now

Comment: @DanielMann the base url is https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}

Comment: Wait a minute. If you're on-prem, then how are you using `dev.azure.com`? That wouldn't work. You're not providing the complete picture which is going to make it very difficult to help you. Please update your question with the **exact** URI you're using. Feel free to redact a bit of it for privacy. Also include what **version** of TFS/Azure DevOps Server you're using.

Comment: @Daniel Mann sorry I should have said that it's in a DMZ so yes on premise. I figured out that the work item type is not Task but in ADO, we customized our work items to have Spanish attached. So all I needed to do was change the work item type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the `'application/json-patch+json'` instead of the `'application/json'` in your code:

```
 _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

If you use the Postman to test the [Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#examples), you will find the error:

```
Valid content types for this method are: application/json-patch+json.
```

That's way we need to use the `application/json-patch+json`

Hope this will help.

Comment: While this isn't what I needed, you are correct on the content type which I noticed after.